# Net charge in a conductor

Tags: electrostatics

Why does the net charge in a conductor with a cavity becomes zero although we find that the field line from the cavity having a charge +q reaches to the surface of the conductor?

Comment: If conductor contain some charge , how can it be zero value .....can you elaborate your question